# How is set different roles and add new role

Tags: php, laravel, laratrust

Im using system where it is using  `$user->is_admin` and `$user->is_employee` and `$user->is_customer` there is no column `is_admin` or `is_employee` or `is_customer` in database. I know that it takes it from user model. but `is_admin` or  `is_employee` is not defined anywhere. and dumping gives me true or false.

I want add new checking like `is_manager`. but cant find where I can add this..

Debugbar isnt showing any query for `is_admin` column..

Where it can be located?

example I have observer:

```
use App\Helper\SearchLog;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class UserObserver
{
    public function roleAttached(User $user, $role, $team)
    {
        if (!$user->is_admin) {
            $type = 'Employee';
            $route = 'admin.employee.edit';

            if ($user->is_customer) {
                $type = 'Customer';
                $route = 'admin.customers.show';
            }

            SearchLog::createSearchEntry($user->id, $type, $user->name, $route);
            SearchLog::createSearchEntry($user->id, $type, $user->email, $route);
        }
    }
```

I dont understand how it knows `is_admin` if it is not in database column?

My user model:

```
namespace App;

use App\Observers\UserObserver;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

    //------------------------------------ Traits ---------------------------

    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use Notifiable;

    //------------------------------------ Attributes ---------------------------

    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::observe(UserObserver::class);
        static::laratrustObserve(UserObserver::class);

    }

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $appends = [
        'user_image_url', 'mobile_with_code', 'formatted_mobile'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    //------------------------------------ Relations ----------------------------

    public function employeeGroup() {
        return $this->belongsTo(EmployeeGroup::class, 'group_id');
    }

    public function todoItems() {
        return $this->hasMany(TodoItem::class);
    }

    public function completedBookings() {
        return $this->hasMany(Booking::class, 'user_id')->where('bookings.status', 'completed');
    }

    public function booking() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Booking::class);
    }

    public function services() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(BusinessService::class);
    }

    public function leave()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Leave', 'employee_id', 'id');
    }

    public function role()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }

    public function employeeSchedule()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\EmployeeSchedules', 'employee_id', 'id');
    }

    //------------------------------------ Scopes -------------------------------

    public function scopeAllAdministrators() {
        return $this->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'administrator');
        });
    }

    public function scopeAllCustomers() {
        return $this->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'customer')->withoutGlobalScopes();
        });
    }

    public function scopeOtherThanCustomers() {
        return $this->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', '<>', 'customer');
        });
    }

    public function scopeAllEmployees() {
        return $this->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'employee');
        });
    }

    //------------------------------------ Accessors ----------------------------

    public function getUserImageUrlAttribute() {
        if (is_null($this->image)) {
            return asset('img/default-avatar-user.png');
        }
        return asset_url('avatar/' . $this->image);
    }

    public function getRoleAttribute() {
        return $this->roles->first();
    }

    public function getMobileWithCodeAttribute() {
        return substr($this->calling_code, 1).$this->mobile;
    }

    public function getFormattedMobileAttribute() {
        if (!$this->calling_code) {
            return $this->mobile;
        }
        return $this->calling_code.'-'.$this->mobile;
    }

    public function routeNotificationForNexmo($notification) {
        return $this->mobile_with_code;
    }

    public function getIsAdminAttribute() {
        return $this->hasRole('administrator');
    }

    public function getIsEmployeeAttribute() {
        return $this->hasRole('employee');
    }

    public function getIsCustomerAttribute() {
        if ($this->roles()->withoutGlobalScopes()->where('roles.name', 'customer')->count() > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //------------------------------------ Mutators -----------------------------

    public function setPasswordAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
    }

    //------------------------------------ Formats -----------------------------

    public function userBookingCount($date) {
        return Booking::whereNull('deal_id')->where('user_id', $this->id)->whereDate('created_at', $date)->get()->count();
    }

} /* end of class */
```

LoginController looks like this where is authenticated class:

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($user->is_admin || $user->is_employee) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard');
        }

        if(!$user->is_admin && !$user->is_employee && Cookie::get('bookingDetails')!==null && Cookie::get('products')!==null && $this->checkUserBooking($user->id)>$this->settings->booking_per_day){
            return redirect(route('front.index'))->withCookie(Cookie::forget('bookingDetails'))->withCookie(Cookie::forget('products'))->withCookie(Cookie::forget('couponData'));
        }
        return redirect(session()->get('url.encoded'));
    }
```

Comment: Carry on up the class hierarcy to `Authenticatable`

Comment: It is checking role(s) associated with user entity. Read about [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) and check again your user model, then you'll see how `is_admin` is checked. The same way you'll be able to make another accessor `is_manager`.

Comment: @Tpojka yes thanks that is it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make another accessor that will check if role is associated with current user entity.

```
public function getIsManagerAttribute() {
    return $this->hasRole('manager');// presuming you have created manager role
}
```

Then you can check easily with

```
// $user = User::find(1);

// $user->is_manager;// true || false
```